# Sandboxing in .NET 4+

Tags: .net, security, appdomain

I was tasked with creating a sandboxed environment for .NET code that our application hosts. I haven't touched the subject for a while and I would like to verify a couple of things.

Before .NET 4 I could define things like "*in AppDomain Foo, only assemblies signed by AcmeCorp authenticode certificate can write to c:\acme folder*".

Is it correct that in .NET 4.0+ I can no longer do that without reverting to the legacy security policy?

Is it correct that all partially trusted assemblies in AppDomain Foo must now have identical permissions, regardless of their origin or publisher? So, I can say either "everyone can write co c:\acme folder" or "no one can write to c:\acme folder"?

Microsoft documentation suggests to use "Software Restriction Policies" (SRP) instead of CAS. Is it correct that with SRP I can say "*only code signed by AcmeCorp can write to c:\acme folder*", but then this restriction would be machine-wide?

Thanks for your answers. Online docs contain a lot of details, but only fellow humans can help with the big picture.